# Comparing angular value with text

Tags: angularjs

I am loading my information in through angular into a view page. I would like to see what the source is (facebook, twitter, blog, etc.) and format my page depending on the source. Something like an if statement in vb script but I am not sure how to do that. So something like this...

```
if {{article.source}} = facebook then 
 <H3> Facebook </H3>
else 
 <H3> Blog </H3> 
end if
```

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h3>{{article.source=='facebook'?'Facebook':'Blog'}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might actually suggest a way other than ifs.

In your controller:

```
$scope.sourceNames = {
  "facebook": "Facebook",
  "blog": "Blog",
  "twitter": "Twitter"
  // etc.
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<h3>{{sourceNames[article.source]}}</h3>
```

Comment: Or maybe that sourceNames object would make more sense in the model or something. My point is that maybe a hash-type solution would make more sense than ifs or a switch or anything like that.